# git fetch with refspec parameter results in empty response

Tags: git, jenkins

I have a problem using the git plugin with jenkins.

jenkins: 1.617
git: 1.9.5.msysgit.1
OS: windows server 2012

The console output of the jenkins job is:

```
Building in workspace C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\Test\workspace
 > git.exe rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree # timeout=10
Fetching changes from the remote Git repository
 > git.exe config remote.origin.url ssh://git@localhost:22/projects/DW.git # timeout=10
Fetching upstream changes from ssh://git@localhost:22/projects/DW.git
 > git.exe --version # timeout=10
using GIT_SSH to set credentials 
 > git.exe -c core.askpass=true fetch --tags --progress ssh://git@localhost:22/projects/DW.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
ERROR: Timeout after 10 minutes
ERROR: Error fetching remote repo 'origin'
```

Based on the Jenkins console output, I checked the behavior of git.exe in the windows console:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\Test\workspace>git.exe -c core.askpass=true
fetch --tags --progress ssh://git@localhost:22/projects/DW.git +re
fs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
Enter passphrase for key '/.ssh/id_rsa':

C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\Test\workspace>
```

However when the command is executed in the terminal without the refspec parameter (`git fetch [<options>] [<repository> [<refspec>…]]`) git responds as expected:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\Test\workspace>git.exe -c core.askpass=true
fetch --tags --progress ssh://git@localhost:22/projects/DW.git
Enter passphrase for key '/.ssh/id_rsa':
From ssh://localhost:22/projects/DW
 * branch            HEAD       -> FETCH_HEAD
```

To check how another repository responds, I used a GitHub repo:

```
C:\gittest>git.exe -c core.askpass=true fetch --tags --progress https://github.
om/skeeto/sample-java-project.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
remote: Counting objects: 423, done.
rReceiving oemote: Total 423 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0), pabjects:  77% (326
Receiving obj
Receiving objects: 100% (423/423), 64.84 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (162/162), done.
From https://github.com/skeeto/sample-java-project
 * [new branch]      lwjgl      -> origin/lwjgl
 * [new branch]      lwjgl-cube -> origin/lwjgl-cube
 * [new branch]      lwjgl-lib  -> origin/lwjgl-lib
 * [new branch]      master     -> origin/master
 * [new branch]      minimal    -> origin/minimal
 * [new branch]      noise      -> origin/noise
 * [new branch]      servlet    -> origin/servlet
```

In addition, I checked the remote directory with the following commands:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\Test\workspace>git remote
origin

C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\Test\workspace>git remote -v
origin  ssh://git@localhost:22/projects/DW.git (fetch)
origin  ssh://git@localhost:22/projects/DW.git (push)

C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\Test\workspace>git branch -r
  origin/master

C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\Test\workspace>git ls-remote
Enter passphrase for key '/.ssh/id_rsa':
From ssh://git@localhost:22/projects/DW.git
a41ca12aa99d2764ff397e7b452ac1e6b2607735        HEAD
a41ca12aa99d2764ff397e7b452ac1e6b2607735        refs/heads/master
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution:

it seems to be a bug in jenkins that has been fixed in unix/linux environment but not in windows:
https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-20879

I removed the passphrase from the id_rsa keyfile (in the right /.ssh/ directory)

```
$ ssh-keygen -p [-P old_passphrase] [-N new_passphrase] [-f keyfile]
```